# How to hide the gui in netbeans?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, hide

I have created a new DesktopApplication in Netbeans. When I start it, it shows the gui directly on the screen. How to hide it after startup?
Something like this:

```
DesktopApplication1.getApplication().getMainFrame().setVisible(false);
```

after the initComponents(); method doesn't work.

Is there a way to hide this window after starting up? (I only want to show it after clicking the tray-Icon of this application. Not after startup.)

Thanks.

This problem is reproduceable when you create a new DesktopApplication in Netbeans. I haven't changed the code (only added the line mentioned above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code for DesktopApplication1App, it says something like

```
//DesktopApplication1App.java
@Action public void startup(){
    show(new DesktopApplication1View(this));
}
```

To fix this, just comment out the show() call, and replacing it with a dummy. For example:

```
//DesktopApplication1App.java
@Action public void startup(){
    Object o = new DesktopApplication1View(this);
}
```

Later, if you want to set it to be visible, you can call this:

```
//DesktopApplication1View.java
DesktopApplication1App.getApplication().show(this);
// ----- OR -----
this.getFrame().setVisible(true);
```

whichever works for you.